# Leaflet - Calculate zoom level from radius in meters

Tags: leaflet, gis, r-leaflet

I'm trying to find a way to calculate zoom level given a radius in meters.

For example, I want to show `100km radius` within `point x,y`, how do I calculate the proper zoom level for that point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will depend on:

- the number of tiles of your map
- the latitude of your view

The resolution (meters/pixel) of a web-Mercator map at zoom 0 (one tile for the whole map) is given by:

`resolution = cos(latitude_rad) * earth circumference / tile width`

with the latitude in radians, the earth circumference in meters (2 * pi * radius) and the map width given by:

`map width = 256`   as the tiles are 256 pixel wide.

At each zoom step, the width (in pixel) is doubled, so at zoom z:
`map width = 256*2^zoom`

so :

`resolution=cos(latitude_rad) * 2*pi* 6371008 / (256*2^zoom)`

but as you are using a certain number **n** of 256 pixel tiles:

`widthmap = cos(latitude_rad) * 2*pi* 6371008*n / (2^zoom)`

Now, to get the zoom from the distance:

with latitude in degrees, radius is your circle in meters, and n the number of tiles to display:

`zoom = floor(log2 ((cos(latitude *pi/180) * 2*pi* 6371008*n)/radius))`

(floor as you want an integer and to make sure your whole circle is on the map)

For example, at 45 degrees N/S, 100m and 1 tile will give you a zoom of 18.